# Xcode 8 beta 6 unwind segue seems broken because "WithSegue" is added to @IBAction unwind method name automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I just realised that, in the current Xcode 8 beta 6, when I hook up an unwind action to, e.g., a bar button item in a modally presented view controller to unwind the modal presentation segue and present the view controller previously in the navigation stack, Xcode adds an "WithSegue" to the name of the existing @IBActions that can be used for this purpose - and that this breaks the unwind segue (it won't be performed). If I edit the storyboard file in source code (as XML), and remove this "WithSegue" from the @IBAction method identifier, the segue works as expected. For example, my unwind method in the originating view controller (the destination for the unwind segue) is called "unwindFromSettingsToTableView" - and Xcode/Interface Builder rename this method to "unwindFromSettingsToTableViewWithSegue" when I CTRL-connect the bar button item in the modally presented view controller to the view controller's exit item in the scene dock.

Is this a bug in Xcode 8 beta? Is it a known bug? Am I missing something?

I checked my previously connected unwind segues (connected in Xcode 7), and they don't have this "WithSegue" suffix. If I delete those existing "vintage" unwind segues, and connect them again in Xcode 8, Interface Builder now suggests the same method name with the "WithSegue" suffix - and those segues break. When I delete the suffix in storyboard source code, the unwind segue works again.

Would be great to get any indications. This behaviour is annoying.

Best wishes!
Björn

Comment: Perhaps you can update question with example of how `unwindFromSettingsToTableView` was declared (e.g. did you use `_` with parameter name?). Also, you might want to try reproducing this behavior you describe in a new test project, because I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe in beta 6. Let's make sure there just isn't some problem with your current project.

Comment: "Is this a bug in Xcode 8 beta" No it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift 3, if you don't want it to add `WithSegue`, define your `@IBAction` method to not name the first parameter:

```
@IBAction func unwindHome(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // this is intentionally blank
}
```

If you don't use that `_` syntax, when it goes to hook up the `@IBAction`, it will add the `WithSegue` to the name.

When I use the above syntax for my unwind action, it works fine in Xcode 8, beta 6.

As an aside, when I don't use the `_` syntax shown above in beta 6, it names the action `unwindHomeWithSegue` but it still works with that longer name, with no editing of the storyboard XML needed. I wonder if your non-functioning unwind segue is a result of some other issue. We need a reproducible example of the problem to diagnose further. Perhaps you can share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, Rob - Dear all, thanks for Your replies - very helpful! I realise I should have mentioned that I am still in Swift 2.3 with that project (albeit in Xcode 8, as said) - and that this seems to be the origin of my original issue: In Swift 2.3, we still have the "old" method naming convention (with no underscore required for the initial method parameter to explicitly denote it should not be named when used in a call). I created a quick new project, using the method name as Rob suggested, and it works without issues now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as OP, using swift 2.3 in xcode 8 beta 6.

[This](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/) post using ios 8 explained how to unwind the segue programmatically. And in step three to select the unwind segue in the Document Outline.

Selecting this and changing `unwindToSecondVCWithSegue` in Action on the upper right side to `unwindToSecondVC` so it matches the code solved my issue.

```
@IBAction func unwindToSecondVC (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("unwindToSecondVC")
}
```

[image: unwindSegue]

Comment: Hi! Thanks - that's what I did. I am still new to Xcode and all this business - I think similar such "weird" behaviours are to be expected with every change to the underlying frameworks or programming language (Swift), i.e., every year in the months following WWDC. :-D Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, swift 3 is a moving target. I tried to update the code to this version whenever a new beta came out. In beta 6 I refactored it down to ver. 2.3. Most of the examples for the FB and AWS SDK's are for ver. 2 and I'll wait until swift 3 have been out for a while before migrating. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This problem still occur with the released version of Xcode 8.0 not just the betas.

What I noticed in an unwind segue though is that the suffix was **"WithUnwindSegue"** instead of *"WithSegue"*

I too was using an swift 2.3 project and created an unwind segue. Similar to the above, while on the storyboard, the fix is to remove **WithUnwindSegue** suffix in the **Action** property (field) of the segue's Attributes Inspector.